# How to Display php code as Color texts

Tags: php, html, css, editor

I plan to start writing blogs about php for beginners. In my Blog Articles I want to display sample php codes. Currently I am using  tag to display php code. It's displaying code in the following format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGlK9.png)

But I want to display code in the following format (like geany editor, sublime edit):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMrrK.png)

Comment: Take a look at the in-built PHP function `highlight_string` and/or `highlight_file`

Comment: SO uses https://github.com/google/code-prettify. You can choose a theme.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Its Working Good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend start using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), which will do exactly what you want :-)

**Javascrip solution:**

**highlight.js** is javascript based project, which can highlight (currently 176 languages) in your website application.

**PHP solution:**

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

*Code (From PHP doc.):*

```
<?php
highlight_string('<?php phpinfo(); ?>');
?>
```

*Output:*

```
<code><span style="color: #000000">
<span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php phpinfo</span><span style="color: #007700">(); </span><span style="color: #0000BB">?&gt;</span>
</span>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `highlight_string` or `highlight_file` would be ideal for you needs.

The first, `highlight_string` takes a string of code and applies various styles to the contents.

```
$file='c:/wwwroot/inc/avatar.php';

highlight_string( file_get_contents( $file ) );
```

The latter reads a file directly and applies the same style transformations

```
highlight_file( $file );
```